# Current Nasa EPIC API image with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm new to APIs and trying to make a simple page with the Nasa EPIC API. What I'm trying to do is show the latest image when the page is first opened or reloaded.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var url = "https://epic.gsfc.nasa.gov/api/natural";
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json'
  }).done(function(data) {
    console.log(data[0]);
    var image = data[0];
    $('.information').text(image.identifier);
    $('h2').text(image.caption);
    $('.avatar img').attr("src", 
"https://epic.gsfc.nasa.gov/archive/natural/2018/06/30/jpg/" + image.image + 
".jpg");
  });
});
```

I've managed to hack an image in by adding a date into the file path in my code but that obviously only shows this single image(/2018/06/30/)... There are some references to php in the documentation with daily image but I don't have knowledge of php yet. any tips on how to get around this?

Comment: “I don't have knowledge of php yet. any tips on how to get around this?”
Yes, read a tutorial on PHP and start coding some easy examples.

Comment: Please refer to their documentation on how to get list for all possible dates. Fetch those dates (https://epic.gsfc.nasa.gov/api/natural/all) and pull the images for each day in further requests. This can be done in JS too. These are many steps and as of now this question is a bit too broad.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this for latest dynamic link:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var url = "https://epic.gsfc.nasa.gov/api/natural";
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json'
  }).done(function(data) {
    console.log(data[0]);
    var image = data[0];
    $('.information').text(image.identifier);
    $('h2').text(image.caption);
    var dt = image.date.split(' ')[0].split('-');
    var imgUrl = "https://epic.gsfc.nasa.gov/archive/natural/";
    imgUrl += dt[0] + "/" + dt[1] + "/" + dt[2] + "/jpg/" + image.image + ".jpg";
    $('.avatar img').attr("src", imgUrl);
  });
});
```